# glDrawArrays with count potentialy exceeding buffer size

Tags: opengl, language-lawyer, access-violation, vertex-shader

I have a vertex shader with no vertex attributes declared. It computes all needed values based on UBOs, `gl_VertexId` and `gl_InstanceID`.

I [know](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/5402/do-i-have-to-have-a-buffer-bound-before-making-a-draw-call) that a nonzero VAO must be bound in order to render.

So is it legal to call a draw command with large `count` argument, while buffers in current VAO state are small, i.e. contain only four `floats`? May it cause video memory access violation due to implicit and unused reading on some platform? Such a draw call seems to work fine on my machine, but I'm not sure if it's safe to run anywhere.

Comment: I think it is a recipe for disaster, in the sense that you don't know how drivers will evolve in the future, even if it might work today on your machine. Secondly, why would you want to exceed your own buffers? Is this some trickery to access memory differently than it would normally be accessed?

Comment: @StarShine I don't want to exceed my buffers. My vertex shader does not access any vertex array buffers at all. But some buffer may still be bound since the previous draw call, and it can be shorter than current draw call might access, if it used a vertex attribute. I afraid that the implementation performs buffer access implicitly. And the purpose of the "trick" is to avoid redundant VAO binding call.

Comment: Sounds like you'd be better off with a compute shader, to make what you're doing more explicit.

Comment: @Robinson I'm limited to OpenGL 3.0 at the time, so I have even no geometry shaders.

Comment: OK well then you have to enforce the contract through other means.  Find a way to ensure there's no buffer bound.  It's probably not that expensive to make the call.

Comment: @Sergey: "*But some buffer may still be bound since the previous draw call*" If your VS does not have any inputs, then the corresponding VAO should not have any enabled array attributes. It's not clear what exactly the concern here is, unless you're trying to avoid changing the VAO to match what you're renderng.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is perfectly legal. Non-zero VAO does not mean attribute count can't be zero. With zero attributes, nothing is read from vertex buffer.

edit: Spec link
https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf

> Client vertex and index arrays - all vertex array attribute and element array
>   index pointers must refer  to buffer objects.   The default vertex array object
>   (the name zero) is also deprecated.  Calling
>   VertexAttribPointer
>   when no
>   buffer object or no vertex array object is bound will generate an
>   INVALID_-
>   OPERATION
>   error, as will calling any array drawing command when no ver
>   tex array object is bound.

But creating and binding "empty" VAO solves the problem. See table on page 580 - initial (and valid) state of VAO has all attributes disabled.

Comment: Good answer, but could you please proof it with a reference to spec or official Khronos documentation?